# is there a twitter user login framework for gae

Tags: python, google-app-engine, frameworks, twitter, oauth

I want to someone to be able to login using twitter,

Is there a framework that you have used to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not exactly addressing your questions I believe these examples and code will be useful:

1. http://github.com/joshthecoder/tweepy
2. http://github.com/joshthecoder/tweepy-examples
3. http://github.com/wasauce/redroosterlabs

Comment: the tweepy-examples is not running  ..  why  ?

Comment: Can you describe the error in more detail? I am successfully running the example on App Engine. Maybe go to the tweepy IRC channel #tweepy. People there can help.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple example [here](http://snipplr.com/view/5954/posting-to-twitter-from-google-appengine/).  Beyond this, there's [tweetapp](http://github.com/tav/tweetapp), but it's currently not maintained; [AppEngine-OAuth-Library](http://github.com/mikeknapp/AppEngine-OAuth-Library); and, I believe, some twitter-friendly delegated authorization framework for Django, [Django-social-auth](http://uswaretech.com/blog/2009/04/develop-twitter-api-application-in-django-and-deploy-on-google-app-engine/), about which, however, I don't know much beyond the name.

Comment: did you know some library that provides various authentication systems for Google App Engine. like gaema http://code.google.com/p/gaema/

Comment: but i am not successful using gaema on twitter

Comment: Why do you need "various" auth systems for GAE to use Twitter?  OAuth should suffice.

Comment: Then that's a completely different question for this one, which says twitter right in the title -- open said completely different question separately, it's absurd to hide it in comments!